# AndroidStudio failed at launch because R cannot found

Tags: java, android, android-studio, compiler-errors

I have a problem with the R file which is generated automatically by Android Studio.

There are all the components connected from the Java code to the XML interface.

At some point at coding it crashes and deletes the R file in all models so I have big problems to restore it and get it back running.

I tried many different things and it happens anytime.

What I am doing wrong or how can I restore or rebuild this R file easily?

Comment: In 3-4 months ago i deleted R file accidently and tried to get it back. Tried Clean Project , Rebuild Project but nothing was helped me. At the end i copied all project folders and created new project and then it generated a new R file for me.

Comment: Sometimes a xml has a little error that is hard to find, and that causes the problem of generating R.

Comment: I did it like the samne way by creating a new project. But i wanted to know if there is a better and more efficency way to solve this ?

Comment: Trying running android lint on when you have these issues. It will go through your code and xml and look for errors.

Comment: @ahdgfd i tried so many ways like invalidate caches, rebuild projects etc.. But only creating new project helped me .

Answer (score 2):

**Try the next step to "Refresh" your IDE (android studio)**

1. Check you don't have any errors inside a `.xml` file
 
2. Go to --> File --> Invalidate Caches/Restart.

Comment: Now i tried to reforce my faillure. So i deleted the R file and did it like this way. I dont know why but at the secound attemp it works. I hope this will work also with my future problems. Thanks for your help.